# Returning C arrays into python scope from scipy's weave.inline

Tags: python, arrays, return, scipy

I am using scipy's weave.inline to perform computationally expensive tasks. I have problems returning an one-dimensional array back into the python scope. Weave.inline uses a special argument called "return_val" for the purpose of returning values back into the python scope.
The following example returning an integer value works well:

```
>>> from scipy.weave import inline
>>> print inline(r'''int N = 10; return_val = N;''')
10
```

However the following example, which indeed compiles without prompting an error, does not return the array i would expect:

```
>>> from scipy.weave import inline
>>> code =\
    r'''                                                              
       int* pairs;                                                       
       int  lenght = 0;                                                      
       for (int i=0;i<N;i++){                                            
         lenght   += 1;                                                     
         pairs     = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*lenght);                       
         pairs[i]  = i;
         std::cout << pairs[i] << std::endl;              
       }                                                                 
       return_val = pairs;                                               
    '''
 >>> N  = 5
 >>> R = inline(code,['N'])
 >>> print "RETURN_VAL:",R
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 RETURN_VAL: 1
```

I need to reallocate the size of the array "pairs" dynamically which is why I can't pass a numpy.array or python list per se.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is use the raw python [c-api calls](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html), or if you're looking for something a bit more convenient, the built in scipy weave wrappers.

No guarantees about leaks or efficiency, but it should look something a bit like this:

```
from scipy.weave import inline

code = r'''
    py::list ret; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        py::list item;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            item.append(j);
        }
        ret.append(item);
    }
    return_val = ret;
    '''
N  = 5 
R = inline(code,['N'])
print R
```

Comment: Work pretty well and so far no sign of leaks or lack of efficiency. Thanks.

Comment: That depends on your problem, using python lists might be ok if the effort for calculating the single elements is very large, the number of elements is low, and if you plan to iterate through the data in a python loop in the end. But since you already decided to use C/C++ for efficiency there is no reason not to go all the way and use C and numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely don't know the size of the output array in advance, you must create it in your inline code. I'm pretty sure that your array allocated by using malloc will result in leaked memory since you have no way of controlling when this memory is to be freed.

The solution is to create a numpy array, fill it with your function's results and return it.

```
import scipy.weave

code = r"""
npy_intp dims[1] = {n};

PyObject* out_array = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
double* data = (double*) ((PyArrayObject*) out_array)->data;

for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) data[i] = i;

return_val = out_array;
Py_XDECREF(out_array);
"""

n = 5
out_array = scipy.weave.inline(code, ["n"])
print "Array:", out_array
```

Comment: It seems to me, that the size of "data" is allocated before the loop. The problem is, that I need to expand the array within the loop, which is why I marked Andrew's solution as correct. Is there a possibility to modify your code for that particular purpose ?

Comment: Arrays can never be expanded in place. In the code in your question you are not expanding the pairs array but creating a new array within each loop, loosing the old one and leaking its memory. I don't know what problem you are trying to solve and if there is absolutely no option to make an efficient 1st pass through the loop in order to determine the final array size.